# Alternative to scipy.sparse for solving sparse linear system with sparse RHS

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

I'm interested in solving a linear system of the form `AX=B`, where `A` and `B` are sparse matrices.

Using `scipy.sparse`, I would typically go about this with

```
X = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A, B)
```

However, in my application, I want to solve this system several times, for different `B`.

The typical approach involves storing the factorization of `A` and using the associated `solve` method.  For example, using `scipy.sparse.linalg.splu`

```
A_inv = splu(A)
for B_i in Bs:
    X_i = A_inv.solve(B_i)
```

But it seems neither `scipy.sparse.linalg.splu` nor `scipy.sparse.linalg.factorize` supports RHS that are sparse matrices.

Besides converting `B` to a dense matrix, are there any other sparse linear algebra packages in python that allow this functionality?